# when running rasa on jupyter notebook this probelm appears ('str' object has no attribute 'event_broker')

Tags: rasa

i followed this tutorial to run rasa on jupyter notebook (https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/jupyter-notebooks/) but when running this line:
from rasa.jupyter import chat

endpoints = "endpoints.yml"
chat(model_path, endpoints)

the problem appears

i edited the endpoints file so the event_broker appears because it was commented but nothing happened and tried to remove the comment from the action_endpoint and nothing happened
it seems like the project file does not see what i am editing in the endpoints file